# What is wrong with this custom query syntax used inside C# code?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

The query looks like this:

```
string query = "IF NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT * from clienti 
 where CodCliente=  ' " + id + " ' 
 AND NomeCliente= ' " + emri + " ' 
 AND RagioneSociale=' " + ragSoc + " ' 
 AND PartitaIVA=' " + piva + " ') 

Insert INTO clienti VALUES(
 ' " + id + 
 " ',' " + emri + 
 " ',' " + ragSoc + 
 " ',' " + piva + " ') 
 else 
  UPDATE clienti 
  SET(' " + id + " ',' " + emri + " ',' " + ragSoc + " ',' " + piva + " ')";
```

I just keep getting the same problem stated below:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from clienti where CodCliente= ' 1 ' AND NomeCliente= ' ' at line 1`

Comment: Perhaps some of variables you have used like `emri` or `piva` or others are wrong. I mean they have some illegal symbols. Check it.

Comment: ok easy way of figuring it out.  Print the query variable out and then run it as it is.  That will help point out where the error is.

Comment: @Kevin She has to invite you to have some beer man! Hahahaah

Comment: You should really use Parameters and not concatenate the value. What happens if emri dontains "', '', ''); DELETE clienti --"

Comment: Don't create your query by concatting strings.  You leave yourself vunerable to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) (both malicious and accidental) and that seems to be biting you.  Use parameterized queries in which you can ensure that the SQL will *always* be valid.

Comment: no the variable name are just fine. i have check and rechecked them the variables are just fine

Comment: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @elena It's not just the *names* of the variables, but their *contents*, because you're treating data as code.  If you use parameterized queries then you can ensure that the content of the variables can't break your query.

Comment: Are you running this code as a stored procedure or as a text command?

Comment: @Servy How can I change my code in a parameterized query can you show me an example please

Comment: @elena Do some research on your own.  There are *lots* and *lots* of tutorials and guides on the subject out there.  The information is very discoverable.

Comment: thanks I will make the research on my own. can you please help me with this other question I want to change this string emri = row["NomeCliente"].ToString(); and make it in a varchar() data type how can I do it

Comment: I wish it were possible to upvote a suggestion in a comment more than once. I would spend a few points to upvote @Kevin 's advice a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `THEN` and `END IF` keywords. Check [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating blank spaces before and after all your variables. Also, make sure all your variables are in string format.